# ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain equivalent for IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, session-cookies, reverse-proxy

I use IIS and URL rewrite as a reverseProxy. My actual webapplication is hosted on a server which is not directly accessible to the internet.

In the rewrite rules I replace the host name of the reverse Proxy with the local IP address. This works fine.

However, the application I use provides downloads. Once the client makes a download request a server side process redirects to the actual download file.

This is where I have issues. It seems like the session cookie (JSESSIONID) is not correctly shared between reverse proxy and local server. Instead of being redirected to the download file, I get a 401 "not authorized" message from the local server.

I found a similar question here.
[How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486498/how-to-properly-set-jsessionid-cookie-path-behind-reverse-proxy)
The user was using Apache as a reverse proxy and was using `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` to rewrite the cookie domain name.

Is there a similar setting in IIS?
I tried the following outbounding rule but this doesn't work.

```
<preCondition name="contains-domain-set-cookie-header">
  <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern=".*?domain=MYDOMAIN*?" />
</preCondition>
<rule name="rewrite cookie domain" preCondition="contains-domain-cookie-header">
  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="^(.*?domain=)MYDOMAIN(.*?)$" negate="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}MYLOCALIP{R:2}" /> 
</rule>
```

Are there other ways to handle this?

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying headers with IIS7 Application Request Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842885/modifying-headers-with-iis7-application-request-routing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841986/iis-aar-url-rewrite-for-reverse-proxy-how-to-send-http-host?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842885/modifying-headers-with-iis7-application-request-routing)

To preserve the Host Header run this from command line to update Machine/webroot/apphost config

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/proxy -preserveHostHeader:true /commit:apphost
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I was literally fighting with IIS for a week trying to get this to work, thanks! :)